# balance the arrays for each index

Tags: php

```
<?php

   $teams = [0 => ['players' => ['marie'=>2342,
                          'paul'=>3632,
                        'vincent'=>2362,
                         'pierre'=>7823,
                         'jean'=>9203]
            ],
            1 => ['players' => []
            ],
            2 => ['players' => []
           ],
            3 => ['players' => []
           ]
     ];


    $all_teams = array_merge($teams[0]['players'],
                             $teams[1]['players'],
                             $teams[2]['players'],
                             $teams[3]['players']);

    $result = array_chunk($all_teams, 1, true);

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        if (isset($result[$i]) && isset($teams[$i])) {

            $teams[$i]['players'] = $result[$i];
        }

    }

     //I want a input of array like

      $teams = [0 => ['players' => ['marie'=>2342, 'jean'=>9203]
           ],
      1 => ['players' => ['paul'=>3632]
           ],
      2 => ['players' => ['vincent'=>2362]
           ],
      3 => ['players' => ['pierre'=>7823]
           ]
     ];
```

Hello, I want to add each player on each team to balance the arrays;
the problem with my code, it puts it in the mess and 'jean' does not count in the array and i want the last element to be added too. and find a better way to balance the tables for each incoming element.

Comment: You only need it balanced?  You do not care where the players end up in the array?

Comment: Exactly, if the arrays are well balanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
$teams = [0 => ['players' => ['marie'=>2342,'paul'=>3632,'vincent'=>2362,'pierre'=>7823,'jean'=>9203]],
          1 => ['players' => []],
          2 => ['players' => []],
          3 => ['players' => []]
 ];

//Get all players and put them into a single array
$players = array_reduce(array_column( $teams, 'players' ),'array_merge',array());
$teamCount = count($teams);

//Clear all Teams
foreach($teams as $key => $team) {
    $teams[$key]['players'] = array();
}

//Assign the playes to the team using mod
foreach(array_keys($players) as $key => $player ) {
    $teams[ $key % $teamCount ]['players'][$player] = $players[$player];
}
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [players] => Array
                (
                    [marie] => 2342
                    [jean] => 9203
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [players] => Array
                (
                    [paul] => 3632
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [players] => Array
                (
                    [vincent] => 2362
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [players] => Array
                (
                    [pierre] => 7823
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I really like your code. very clean is professional your code is what I look for thank you for your help! @Eddie

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: @Eddie I also agree.  I like the use of the array_reduce with the array_column function.  I also liked the the array_keys($players), I had no idea you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.  It counts total players and then redistributes according to how many players you want on a team.

```
function balanceTeams($teams, $playersPerTeam, $shuffle = NULL){

  //Get total players in array
  $playerCount = 0;
  foreach($teams as $team){

    foreach($team['players'] as $player=>$id){

    $players[] = array('name' => $player, 'id'=>$id);

    }

  }

  $playerCount = count($players);

  if($shuffle){

   shuffle($players);

  }


  //Make your new array
  $count = 0;
  $team = 0;

  for($i = 0; $i < $playerCount;  $i += $playersPerTeam){

    for($j = 0; $j < $playersPerTeam; $j++){

        if($players[$count]['id']){

          $results[$team]['players'][$players[$count]['name']] = $players[$count]['id'];

        }else {

          break;

        }

        $count++;
    }

  $team++;


  }

return $results;


}
```

How to use:

```
$teams = [0 => ['players' => ['marie'=>2342,
                          'paul'=>3632,
                        'vincent'=>2362,
                         'pierre'=>7823,
                         'jean'=>9203]
            ],
            1 => ['players' => []
            ],
            2 => ['players' => []
           ],
            3 => ['players' => []
           ]
     ];

$playersPerTeam = 2;
$shuffle = NULL;  //Set to 1 to shuffle.

$results = balanceTeams($teams, $playersPerTeam, $shuffle);

print_r($results);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [players] => Array
                (
                    [marie] => 2342
                    [paul] => 3632
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [players] => Array
                (
                    [vincent] => 2362
                    [pierre] => 7823
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [players] => Array
                (
                    [jean] => 9203
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: @Nicolas Lefevre   Look at update.  I added a shuffle parameter so you can shuffle teams if you want.

Comment: Undefined offset.. replace if($players[$count]['id']){ to  if(isset($players[$count]['id'])){ to check that it exists. another problem.. I can't set 1 to $playersPerTeam, making several loops and trying to make the array better accesible in this way you do the opposite ... @Joseph_J

Comment: Are you sure you copied my code correctly.  I just ran it with $playersPerTeam = 1 and it worked correctly.

Comment: Your code is huge and when I var_dump ($teams) nothing changes you wrong set the values. the $results change.. but not the $teams. @ Joseph_J

Comment: I'm sorry you don't like it.  It works just fine on my machine with the data that you provided.  You have already accepted Eddie's answer, which by the way is the best answer on this page.  It should do you just fine.

Comment: Yes, Thanks anyway for your help! @ Joseph_J

Answer (score 0):

**function:**

```
function mixPlayers($teams)
{
    $r = [];
    array_walk_recursive($teams, function ($v, $k) use (&$r) {
        if (!is_array($v)) {
            $r[] = [$k => $v];
        }
    });
    return $r;
}


function assign($players, $need)
{
    $res = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($players); $i++) {
        $index = $i % $need;
        $res[$index]['players'] = array_merge(
            isset($res[$index]['players']) ? $res[$index]['players'] : [],
            $players[$i]
        );
    }
    return $res;
}
```

**usage:**

```
$res = assign( mixPlayers($teams) , 4);
var_export($res);
```